# c# tableLayoutPanel with dynamic userControls scroll issue

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, smooth-scrolling, tablelayoutpanel

i'm working on win-form (c#) that contains tableLayoutPanel, the panel contain only one column, but various number of rows with userControl in it, added by user at run time.
each userControl (all the same) contains ultraGrid with various number of lines in it (4-15 max).
the default scenario is that the tableLayoutPanel contains 3 rows, each row contains 1 userControl.
the panel set to autoScroll as the form cannot view all controls.
the issue is while vertically scrolling the panel, it looks really bad, and the userControl seems like stretching until i leave the scroll bar.
is there any way to make the scroll more smooth?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Are the appropriate `DoubleBuffered` settings set to true?

Comment: Yes it is, for all userControls and panel